# Hand written character recognition using neural network

Tags: c#, image-processing, neural-network, handwriting

i need some guide lines and help to develop this ANN. i don't have any past experience with neural networks and this is little bit hard for me. i want to recognize handwriting using this..

any help would be nice..

:-|

Comment: Is using a neural network one of the requirements?  Is the handwriting data in a particular domain, i.e. addresses, numbers, signatures?  A neural net might not be the best solution.

Comment: Neural networks have to be trained before they become functional.  You are going to get a serious case of writers' cramp before you get there.  It takes a very advanced one like the human brain at least 6 years.  Labor of love, really.

Comment: https://github.com/mesutpiskin/characterRecognition It helps you understand the concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an open source c# OCR:

http://neurondotnet.freehostia.com/samples/ocr.html

Comment: The link is not functional any more. Do you have some other link or solution?