# Gesture to text recognition, OCR or Gesture based, native .NET library

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, ocr, gesture-recognition

I'm working on a project for Windows Phone 7 and what I need is a library for recognizing shapes into text.
The current task is very simple. I have a canvas, and I use `Touch.FrameReported` event to detect the points and just add them to a `Polyline` inside the canvas. Next I need this Polyline (which I can convert to bitmap, shape, whatever) to be recognized as a letter, closest match.
I don't want service based library. Everything I've found so far are wrappers around COM functions. It appears there's not any good OCR library written entirely in managed code that could be used in a WP7 environment.

I would even go that far as to write my own library if I can get a hold of a simple algorithm for shape comparison based on lines.

Comment: Did you try OpenCV/EmguCV? I am not sure if it works on the phone.

Comment: EmguCV is a wrapper for OpenCV which not managed code.

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski, its not possible. check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002402/ocr-for-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open source c# OCR library here:

http://neurondotnet.freehostia.com/samples/ocr.html

Not sure how WP7 compatible it is though. See these related questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744966/any-open-source-c-sharp-ocr-library

[Hand written character recognition using neural network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403287/hand-written-character-recognition-using-neural-network)

Comment: NeuronDotNet looks very promissing and works with point data comparison. I'll give it a spin and see if it can be used on WP7 without modification, although I suspect it references System.Drawing, but I don't need all functionality anyway. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to convert neurondotnet. But it appears to me ISerializable interface is not present for WP-SL. Anyone else got any luck converting this lib?

Comment: I tried as well, but gave up after hours of code refactoring. Then I read about Microsoft gesture recognition, and totally lost interest in doing it myself. http://wmpoweruser.com/microsoft%E2%80%99s-next-generation-gesture-search-technology-coming-to-mobile-and-pcs-soon/