# Scanning Text (OCR) in Windows Phone 7.5

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, ocr, zxing

Is there a way to force [Zxing library](http://silverlightzxing.codeplex.com/) to scan text only? I am looking for the offline (non-cloud) solution to scan text in windows phone.

OR

The integrated Bing vision successfully scans text from the image. Is there a way to call the same task in our application (something like Microsoft.Phone.Tasks)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, there's no native .NET OCR engines. In theory, you could use any OCR SDK that worked for Win CE (as long as WP7 is based on it), but in practice - i haven't seen any working solution yet and all OCR applications for WP7 that i've seen were based on cloud services. I can point you to some ready to go cloud solutions if you'd change your mind about web API.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay. You are right. I tried to convert [NeuronDotNet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/neurondotnet/) but among other issues, it looks like ISerializable interface is not supported in silverlight for wp.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for OCR solutions, you could use this so [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742339/gesture-to-text-recognition-ocr-or-gesture-based-native-net-library).

Regarding bing vision - there's no support for third-party developers yet. Though there's a project called Hawaii (yes, it's cloud-based) that's probably going to be the gateway for bing vision ocr.

Comment: The Project Hawaii program was discontinued on October 8, 2013.