# Scan text function Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I would like to know if it is possible to copy text from "Scan Text" Function [Scan Text MSDN](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/web/scan-codes-tags-and-text)  and use in my app ?
On my app it will be button to move to scan text page and after when user has finished scanned it will be return to my app with text .
Is it possible to do this ?

Comment: I dont think the OCR library is available to use yet

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/10168986/1230188